# iphone programming objective-c : draw destination on mkmap

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations

i have an application that show the user location and put MKAnnotation each 5 minutes on the map. It is possible to link all the placemarks with a line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to save all the points and draw a `MKPolyline` on the map overlay. here is a sample project that does that: [Drawing polyines or routes on a MKMapView in iOS4](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136).